# i need to add one input value after key word APP PATH in configure file through .bat script

Tags: batch-file

There is one configure file, where APP PATH is key word

```
APP Path vijay ajay rajesk abcdf defc
```

I need to add input value like `tyupo_gty`

```
APP Path tyupo_gty vijay ajay rajesk abcdf defc
```

again some other need to add input like `tgtgqwe`.Now like should look like

```
APP Path tgtgqwe tyupo_gty vijay ajay rajesk abcdf defc
```

And so on

Answer (score 0):

I took here test.txt as Configuration file :

```
@echo off&cls

set "$confFile=C:\vijay\edasprof.prf"
set /p "$add=Enter the value4 to add : "

(for /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%a in (%$confFile%) do (
 if "%%a%%b"=="APPPATH" (echo %%a %%b %$add% %%c
   ) else (echo %%a %%b %%c)
))>temp.txt
move temp.txt %$ConfFile%
```

Without temp file try like this :

```
@echo off&cls

set "$confFile=C:\vijay\edasprof.prf"
set /p "$add=Enter the value4 to add : "

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "$c=1"
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%a in (%$confFile%) do (     
 if "%%a%%b"=="APPPATH" (set ##!$c!=%%a %%b %$add% %%c
   ) else (set ##!$c!=%%a %%b %%c)
set /a $c+=1
)

(for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set ##') do echo %%a)>%$confFile%
```

Comment: @echo off&cls

set /p "$add=Enter the value to add : "
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%a in (C:\vijay\edasprof.prf) do echo %%a %%b %$add% %%c > C:\vijay\edasprof.prf .i ran this script.my configure file is lost on data and only this will be there SET SMARTMODE vijayhari = ON . please advice there is only one key work APP PATH and we need to insert input fater that

Comment: Is ADD PATH always at the start of the line ? like in your snippet ?

Comment: Give a real situation snippet please

Comment: -* Profile generated on 05 August 2013 at 14:06:20
APP PATH migration iaamcim distprodmig sharedmfds trac_ftp trac_prod_unix trn_rfmdev vijayatest -*
-* DEFAULT SERVER SETTINGS
-*************
-*SET OPSYSCMD = ON

this is config file.we need to add application folder name which input add into APP PATH,rest item will escap for right hand side

Comment: ADD PATH is alwaysat the start of the line ?

Comment: i am ok with chat as well,if Sachdee is fine with that

Comment: Awesome.but this is configure file ,we don't want to create temp.txt file and move to correct configure file.Meanwhile time some is doing something change,they missed the part with our configure file.

Comment: can we do in same config file directly  intead of temp.txt file and move to config file

Comment: it is some weird behaviour.it is coped into random middle of file.it takes all APP Path folder and paste there in  middle.

Comment: please help on this -SachaDee

Comment: are you Sache Dee busy ?